# How to uninstall Skype for Business from Microsoft 365 package?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, office365, skype-for-business

I installed on my computer Microsoft 365 Pro package for students (https://products.office.com/pl-pl/student/office-in-education). With this package in addition to Word, PowerPoint etc. Skype for Business is also delivered. In "Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features" I can only uninstall entire "Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise" (formerly "Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus").

PS Removing this program from autostart is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of apps other than Word, PowerPoint, Excel and OneNote by manually removing certain files from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16", that are listed below.

I diffed two folders - one with files from Office 2019 Home&Student, and the second one with files from Office 365 Education (a version that I use), and removed files that existed only in the second folder. This is probably a very bodge way to do this, but it worked for me.

If someone would want to remove those files I **highly** recommend to create a backup.

```
ACCICONS.EXE
ACCWIZ.DLL
ACEDAO.DLL
AppSharingChromeHook64.dll
AppSharingHookController64.exe
Appshapi.dll
AutoHelper.dll
CNFNOT32.EXE
CONTAB32.DLL
CommunicatorContentBinApp.xap
DLGSETP.DLL
EMABLT32.DLL
EMSMDB32.DLL
ENVELOPE.DLL
EXSEC32.DLL
ExtensibleApp.xap
HeaderPatterns.xml
LYNC.EXE.MANIFEST
Lync2013_Third_Party_Notices.txt
LyncDesktopSmartBitmapResources.dll
MAPIPH.DLL
MAPISHELL.DLL
MIMEDIR.DLL
MLCFG32.CPL
MORPH9.DLL
MSACC.OLB
MSACCESS.EXE
MSACCESS.VisualElementsManifest.xml
MSAEXP30.DLL
MSOUTL.OLB
MSPST32.DLL
MSPUB.EXE
MSPUB.TLB
MSPUB.VisualElementsManifest.xml
MSRTEDIT.DLL
Media
MeetingJoinAxOC.dll
Microsoft.Lync.Model.zip
Microsoft.Lync.Utilities.Controls.zip
Microsoft.Lync.Utilities.zip
NL7Data0011.DLL
NL7Lexicons0011.DLL
NL7Models0011.DLL
NativeHostAnnotationApp.xap
NativeHostPollApp.xap
OCHelper.dll
OCIntlDate.dll
OCSAEXT.dll
OLKFSTUB.DLL
OLMAPI32.DLL
OMSMAIN.DLL
OMSXP32.DLL
OUTLCTL.DLL
OUTLLIBR.COMMON.DLL
OUTLMIME.DLL
OUTLOOK.EXE
OUTLOOK.EXE.MANIFEST
OUTLOOK.VisualElementsManifest.xml
OUTLPH.DLL
OUTLRPC.DLL
OUTLVBS.DLL
OcOffice.dll
OcPubMgr.exe
Ocomprivate.zip
OutlookServicing.DLL
OutlookWebHost.dll
PRTF9.DLL
PSTPRX32.DLL
PTXT9.DLL
PUB6INTL.COMMON.DLL
PUBCONV.DLL
PUBTRAP.DLL
PropertyModel.dll
PropertyModelProxy.dll
Psom.dll
RECALL.DLL
REMINDER.WAV
RSWOP.ICM
RTMPLTFM.dll
Rtmcodecs.dll
Rtmmediamanager.dll
Rtmmvras.dll
Rtmmvrsplitter.dll
Rtmpal.dll
SCANPST.EXE
SCNPST32.DLL
SCNPST64.DLL
SCNPST64C.DLL
SENDTO.DLL
SHAREPOINTPROVIDER.DLL
SOA.DLL
SOCIALCONNECTOR.DLL
SOCIALPROVIDER.DLL
UCAddin.dll
UCMAPI.EXE.MANIFEST
UCRTBASE.DLL
Uc.dll
UcMapi.exe
UccApi.dll
Ucmp.dll
Win32MsgQueue.dll
amRenderer.js
appsharingmediaprovider.dll
appshcom.dll
appshvw.dll
bdcmetadata.xsd
bdcmetadataresource.xsd
lync.exe
lync.ico
lync99.exe
lyncDesktopViewModel.dll
lyncModelProxy.dll
lynchtmlconv.exe
lynchtmlconvpxy.dll
msaccess.exe.manifest
mset7.dll
mset7db.kic
mset7en.kic
mset7es.kic
mset7fr.kic
mset7ge.kic
mset7jp.kic
mset7tk.dll
mset7tkjp.dll
msfad.dll
msoev.exe
msoia.exe
msoianetutil.dll
msotd.exe
msotdaddin.dll
mspub.exe.manifest
ocimport.dll
ocmsptls.dll
ocogl.dll
ocpptview.dll
ocppvwintl.dll
ocrec.dll
olReadingPane.js
rdpqoemetrics.dll
roottools.dll
rtmmvrcs.dll
rtmmvrhw.dll
rtmvc1decmft.dll
scdec.dll
ssscreenvvs.dll
tmpod.dll
windowsspeakerrecosdk.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

As the Microsoft says, it should be "If you are using Office 365 Skype for Business, you can't delete it from your computer without also uninstalling the rest of the Office suite. This because it's integrated with the other Office apps. " See this link : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-skype-for-business-28c4a036-7f22-406c-b7f4-87894cbaf902

Comment: Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall Office 365. Instead of the computer getting rid of everything, a prompt may pop up asking to either repair the installation or uninstall everything or uninstall certain components. Or if you want to be on the safe side, type this into Google ,"How to uninstall certain components in Office 365".